# Merge guest account with StackExchange account

Tags: support, status-completed

Can an admin please merge my guest account with my StackExchange account? I messed up migrating the guest account to a full account.

Guest Account: https://serverfault.com/users/89184/waleed-ahmad

StackExchange Account: https://serverfault.com/users/89190/waleed-ahmad

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801 for future reference, but this really belongs on Meta.SF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done